# JOLT transform добавить префикс для спецификации распределения массива объектов

Tags: json

Прошу помощи:
Есть документ вида

```
{
  "_id": 100,
  "CreatedDate": "2021-00-00 00:00:32+0300",
  "UpdatedDate": "2022-00-01 00:00:48+0300",
  "RequestedDocumentsList": [
    {
      "DocumentType": 11,
      "FileType": 11,
      "ReferenceId": "ref1",
      "FileComment": null,
      "IsAttached": false
    },
    {
      "DocumentType": 12,
      "FileType": 12,
      "ReferenceId": "ref2",
      "FileComment": null,
      "IsAttached": false
    }
  ]
}
```

для этого документа подготовлена спецификация

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Documents": {
        "*": {
          "@": "[&1]",
          "@(2,_id)": "[&1]._id"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Нужно получить вывод вида:

```
[ {
  "DC_DocumentType" : 11,
  "DC_FileType" : 11,
  "DC_ReferenceId" : "ref1",
  "DC_FileComment" : null,
  "DC_IsAttached" : false,
  "_id" : 100
}, {
  "DC_DocumentType" : 12,
  "DC_FileType" : 12,
  "DC_ReferenceId" : "ref2",
  "DC_FileComment" : null,
  "DC_IsAttached" : false,
  "_id" : 100
} ]
```

т.е. добавить префикс DC_ для всех атрибутов кроме _id в одной спецификации.
Есть понимание как прогнать это через еще одну трансформацию для получения нужного результата, но можно ли сделать в одной?

Пробовал указывать префиксы в данных строках, но так и не победил(

```
  "@": "[&1]",
  "@(2,_id)": "[&1]._id"
```

Answer (score 0):

так попробуйте

```
[{
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "RequestedDocumentsList": {
        "*": {
          "*": "[&1].DC_&",
          "@(2,_id)": "[&1]._id"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

тут прям "кладезь": https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#inception

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]